# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - command-line argument

Tags: java

Hi guys! I have some problems with arg's array.

the Error that program give me is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 at file1.main(file1.java:14)

my program is:

```
public class FC1{
    public static void main (String[]arg){
      String[] primoArray = new String[10];
      primoArray[0] = arg[1];
      primoArray[1] = arg[2];
    }
}
```

can you help me??

Comment: `arg[1]` and `arg[2]` reference the 2nd and 3rd argument respectively - please make sure you pass them as the application parameters. Arrays in Java are 0-based.

Comment: you need to pass arguments first

Answer (score 2):

You're assign args when there are no args. Are you sure that the program is being called with multiple command line arguments?

If this were my program, I'd check the length of the arg array before trying to use items in it.

Also, perhaps you actually meant to use arg[0] and arg[1] since Java arrays are 0 based.

e.g.,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String[] primoArray = new String[10];
  if (args.length >= 2) {
      primoArray[0] = args[0];
      primoArray[1] = args[1];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the length of `arg` array ?Do you pass any arguments to your java program ? If no then array `arg` is empty and you cannot access elements 1, 2.

FYI first element in `arg` is `arg[0]`